# ASN.1 sequence with missing tag/length field

Tags: tags, sequence, asn.1

I'm implementing a specification that, as the outermost data type, specifies a sequence

```
LogMessage ::= SEQUENCE {
   version INTEGER (4),
   ...
}
```

When encoded, I would expect the messages to always start with `30`, but this is not the case. Indeed what I see when  I look at the messages is that the inner part of the `SEQUENCE` is encoded, but the outer definition (`30` and length field of payload) is omitted.

I cannot find why this is happening (the ASN.1 looks just "normal"). Is there a special mode in which this behavior can be seen? Of course I can "manually" trucate that leading data, but I would like to build a robust solution and if this is somehow defined in ASN.1, I'm sure my library (pyasn1) would have an option to set it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share the fragment of your code that encodes this sequence using pyasn1?

Comment: I just use pyasn1.codec.der.encoder.encode(seq) right now. Is there another function I should be using?

Comment: This is the function you need to use. When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example